# Android Worklight App UI Performance Bad vs. Browsers

Tags: android, performance, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, ibm-mobilefirst

In our project we are using JQuery Mobile 1.3.1, WL 5.0.6 and Knockout 2.2.1.

The UI performance of the compiled, bundled and installed Worklight App is in pretty much every aspect - slide transitions, page transitions, button click responsiveness, etc. - quite bad on high-end Android Galaxy 3, Galaxy 4 and LG Optimus G phones.

When we tested the Applications straight from the Consumer Version Tomcat Worklight Server using /worklight/apps/services/preview/App/android/1.0/default/App.html the performance in all browsers on all Android phones - Built-In, Chrome, Firefox, Opera was great. Was very comparable to iOS, even better in some cases. Of course you have the load times of the web resources from the server, but once it is loaded it is fast!

We looked for some solutions and only found the proposal of:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

... but since this should be default from Android API Version 14 we do not expect any real performance increases.

Are there any suggestions how to get a Worklight App to the same performance as the App in the Android browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known and on our radar...

Please see Ishai's answer in this question: [IBM Worklight: UI Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732828/ibm-worklight-ui-performance).
The suggested tweaks to the AndroidManifest.xml file should help in increasing UI performance when using jQuery Mobile in a Hybrid application with the Android environment.

Comment: wow. THANK YOU for the Link and Tipps ... it really makes a difference with JQuery! Are these changes part of WL6 as default?

Comment: No, they are not. Not yet.

Comment: it is really an amazing performance and correct-rendering bump in our app. impressive.