# IBM Worklight - UI is lagging while changing device orientation

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I have made a Worklight application using jQuery Mobile v1.3.1 and I am facing an issue while changing the orientation from portrait to landscape and viceversa.

Issues:

1. It takes time for managing the UI according to Landscape or portrait
   when rotate.
2. While rotating from portrait to landscape, on half rightside white
   area display for 2-3 second then it manages automatically.

Android OS Version : 4.0.0
Worklight Version: 6.0

Answer (score 1):

Try Ishai's suggestion, given in this question: [IBM Worklight: UI Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732828/ibm-worklight-ui-performance)

Quote:

> In your `AndroidManifest.xml`
>
> 1. Replace `<supports-screens ...>` node with the following: 
>      `<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
>      android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
>      android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />`
> 2. Replace `<uses-sdk ...>` node with  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"android:targetSdkVersion="17" />` and move
>      **direct after** `<supports-screens>` Node.
> 3. Add `screenSize` to `android:configChange` attribute under main Activity.
> 4. Build against SDK Version which greater than 3.2. (Click properties on your Android  project and then click on Android, see screenshot).

In general there were several performance changes in the upcoming Worklight 6.1.0 that should make noticeable difference when using jQuery Mobile in Android.

Comment: Add more information to the question: Android OS version, Worklight version and if possible minimize your app to a simple app so that it will contain the bare minimum of what is required to recreate the issue; if you can, upload somewhere the Worklight project too.

Comment: Android OS Version : 4.0.0
Worklight Version: 6.0

Comment: Thanks. Please also upload somewhere the Worklight project where this happens to you.