# IBM Worklight - How to avoid UI flickering while using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a small application by using IBM Worklight with jQuery Mobile.
I have designed three screens in the application.

When I move from one screen to the other I have used:

```
    $.mobile.changepage('nextPage.html')
```

When the next screen loads, its UI is flickering.

Any suggestions have to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, consider the answer in the following question, which improves jQuery Mobile performance in Worklight-based apps where the Android environment is used: [IBM Worklight: UI Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732828/ibm-worklight-ui-performance)

Answer (score 0):

The flicker comes from the default fade animation. Depending on the animations you are using for page transitions, it will look different. Some browsers don't handle it so well and flicker. Use a different transition or just don't at all for the older devices.